# React gh-pages failed to load

Tags: reactjs, github, create-react-app, github-pages

I tried to host my local project using react gh-pages but failed due to below error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q98nD.png)

Comment: It's difficult to know what's the problem just with the description you have given. Alternatively, try to host your app on glitch.com

Comment: Hi Deepak, please describe your problem in detail and also what steps you have taken so far in an attempt to resolve it. Also do mention the programming language as well as the setup you have at the moment for your work. Please try to be simple and clear in your description as it helps others to quickly understand the problem and guide you accordingly.